# Calculate average amount of time spend watching TV

Tags: python, average

Can you help me with this code? I'm not sure how to code where the user enter values until he enters -1.

You want to write up a program which calculates the average amount of time you spend watching tv each day. Allow the user to enter values until he enters -1. Once -1 is entered, calculate the average amount minutes the user had watched tv over the amount of days entered.

Comment: I would recommend writing out in English what you need to do in high level steps, then proceed from there. For example, some of the high level steps in this would be: 1) Prompt user to enter numbers. 2) Get number from user. 3) Check if number is -1. If it is, go to the next step, otherwise, go back. 4). Calculate average. Stack overflow will not write your program for you, you need to show the effort you've made towards solving your problem first.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
result = 0
count = 0

while (time := int(input(f"Day {count}: "))) != -1:
    result += time 
    count += 1

result /= count

print(result)
```

Until the user inputs `-1`, the program appends the inserted time to the variable `result` and increments a counter.

After the while loop ends, it divides the result by the count, obtaining the average amount of time spent watching TV.

Comment: Took me awhile but I solved it!! Yay inVal = input("Enter time in minutes: ")

res = []
while int(inVal) != -1:    
    res.append(inVal)
    inVal = input("Enter time in minutes: ")

for i in range(len(res)):
    res[i] = int(res[i])

print("Average time = ", sum(res) / len(res), "minutes")